# Apply style to first child?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Is there some way to apply styles to the first (or last or nth) child of a container (anything that contains children)? I am trying to customize the look of tab items so that the first one has different border radius than the others.

This is what I have now:

```xml
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
    <Grid>
        <Border Name="Border" BorderBrush="#666" BorderThickness="1,1,1,0" CornerRadius="8,8,0,0" Margin="0,0,0,-1">
            <TextBlock x:Name="TabItemText" Foreground="#444" Padding="6 2" TextOptions.TextFormattingMode="Display">
                <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentSite" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" ContentSource="Header" Margin="12,2,12,2"/>
            </TextBlock>
        </Border>
    </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For ItemsControl derived classes (such as TabControl), you can use the ItemContainerStyleSelector dependency property.  When this dependency property is set, ItemsControl will call StyleSelector.SelectStyle() for each item in the control.  This will allow you to use different styles for different items.

The following example changes the last tab item in a TabControl so its text is bold and a bit larger than the other tabs.

First, the new StyleSelector class:

```
class LastItemStyleSelector : StyleSelector
{
    public override Style SelectStyle(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        var itemsControl = ItemsControl.ItemsControlFromItemContainer(container);
        var index = itemsControl.ItemContainerGenerator.IndexFromContainer(container);

        if (index == itemsControl.Items.Count - 1)
        {
            return (Style)itemsControl.FindResource("LastItemStyle");
        }

        return base.SelectStyle(item, container);
    }
}
```

This style selector will return the style with the key "LastItemStyle" but only for the last item in the control.  The other items will use the default style.  (Note, that this function only uses members from ItemsControl.  It could also be used for other ItemsControl derived classes.)  Next, in your XAML, you first need to create two resources.  The first resource will be to this LastItemStyleSelector and the second resource is the style.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:LastItemStyleSelector x:Key="LastItemStyleSelector" />

    <Style x:Key="LastItemStyle" TargetType="TabItem">
        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="16" />
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

Then finally your TabControl:

```
    <TabControl ItemContainerStyleSelector="{StaticResource LastItemStyleSelector}">
        <TabItem Header="First" />
        <TabItem Header="Second" />
        <TabItem Header="Third" />
    </TabControl>
```

For more information see the MSDN documentation:

- [ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyleSelector Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemcontainerstyleselector.aspx)
- [StyleSelector Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms612988.aspx)

Comment: This won't work for dynamic content as @rFactor apparently needs, as the ItemContainers are not recreated when a new tab is added. So, add a "new" tab at the end, and it too will be assigned the "LastItemStyle."

Answer (score 1):

Unlike  HTML and CSS, there's not a simple way to determine and trigger that type of change.

You could potentially write a trigger and use a value converter to do something like that using [this forum post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/139bed8b-8eb0-4aec-a9c0-521bd7bede91/) as inspiration potentially.

Much simpler would be to apply a custom style to the tabitem that you want to look different. Have you tried that?

```
<TabItem Header="TabItem" Style="{DynamicResource FirstTabStyle}">
    <Grid Background="#FFE5E5E5"/>
</TabItem>
```

Comment: The thing is that tabs are reordered, removed and added at anytime. So I would need to add those styles as well (and remove).

Comment: OK -- your question didn't state that requirement. :)