# How to style last (or first) child of StackPanel differently than the rest?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I'm applying styles to StackPanel:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type StackPanel}">
    <Style.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}" BasedOn="{StaticResource TextboxStyle}">
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,0,5"/>
        </Style>
    </Style.Resources>
</Style>
```

Basically, it adds margin on bottom of every TextBox in StackPanel. What is bad, that last child will have unnecessary margin. So I need to reset it to zero, but only for that last element. WPF is certainly not a CSS, which have :last-child selector and it's probably more quirky to do that.

Comment: Well, I figured out, that setting negative margin to could improve things a bit: `<StackPanel Margin="0,0,0,-5" />`. It cancels last-child positive margin, so it looks fine. But it's just a hack, not a real solution.

Comment: You want to use a style selector, this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9444536/apply-style-to-first-child) has the required function to help you. The top answer seems to be exactly what you are looking for.